# Objective C: add contact to xmpp framework via app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am doing Chat App. XMPP Framework, automatically fetch contacts from ejabbered server. I am unable to add contacts to **ejabbered server** through my app. For ex: If I login through iOS Client, **Jitsi**, there I can give add contact. That too immediately reflect in my app and ejabbered server automatically. I dont know how to add my phone book contacts to ejabbered via my app.

Kindly guide how to add contact through my app.

**Coding**

```
- (void)setupStream
{

XMPPJID jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@localhost", 
                                            `addBuddyTextField.text]];
[appDelegate.xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:addBuddyTextField.text];

xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];

xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding contacts first you need to send subscribe message to destination user (if destination user is registered to XMPP)

**Send subscribe message**

```
 - (void) sendSubscribeMessageToUser:(NSString*)userID
{
    XMPPJID* jbid=  [XMPPJID jidWithString:userID];
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"subscribe" to:jbid];
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
}
```

**when destination user received subscribe message**

```
/**
 This fuction is called when other user state is changed
 */
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);


    NSString *presenceType = [presence type];            // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
    NSString* presenceState= [presence status];

    NSLog(@"%@  is %@ state %@",presenceFromUser,presenceType,presenceState);

   if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribe"])
        {

            [xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:[presence from]];
        }
    else if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribed"])
    {
        [xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:[presence from]];
    }

}
```

these functions will add automatically destination user to your contact list